# how to find out activity doing an Action

Tags: android, android-intent, action

I am perfroming various actions like ACTION_SEND with CreateChooser.  I would like to know what activity the user actualy used for the action.  The only way I can see to do this is to do my own custom ACTION_CHOOSER style dialog.  I was wondering if there is any simple alternative e.g. Is it possible to find out the previous activity when the user gose back to my activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to find out the previous activity when the user gose back to my activity?

No, sorry. Either create your own chooser, or do not worry about which app the user chooses.